# 'LANG_CUR' is not a procedure or is undefined ORA-06550 Error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been trying to fetch 1 column from a table using reference cursor in plsql, table only has 11 column lang_cur is the declared cursor.

```
    create or replace PACKAGE  MOVIE_PKG
    AS
    PROCEDURE lang_display(lang_cur out SYS_REFCURSOR);
    END MOVIE_PKG;

    create or replace PACKAGE BODY MOVIE_PKG
    AS
    PROCEDURE lang_display(lang_cur out SYS_REFCURSOR)
    as
    begin
    OPEN lang_cur FOR select lang_name from LANGUAGE_SELECT;
    end lang_display;
    END MOVIE_PKG;
    
    declare
    lang_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    begin
    movie_pkg.lang_display(lang_cur);
    for data in lang_cur
    loop
    dbms_output.put_line('langauge:'||data.lang_name);
    end loop;
    end;
```

**GETTING THIS ERROR**
(Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 13:
PLS-00221: 'LANG_CUR' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
0655000000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:)

Comment: The `for r in cursorname loop` construction only works with static cursors, not `sys_refcursor`. You'll need to define your own record and code the `fetch` yourself, or else use static cursor (`cursor lang_cur is ...`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FETCH`:

```sql
declare
  lang_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  lang_name LANGUAGE_SELECT.LANG_NAME%TYPE;
begin
  movie_pkg.lang_display(lang_cur);

  LOOP
    FETCH lang_cur INTO lang_name;
    EXIT WHEN lang_cur%NOTFOUND;
    
    dbms_output.put_line('langauge:'||lang_name);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE lang_cur;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a06c75a0ba05c382f95b2b3808ebd583)*

Comment: Thank you sir it worked ,also we have to close cursor in static only right?

Comment: @GauravRastogi Yes, you're correct and should close the cursor. It should be implicitly closed when the block ends but you shouldn't rely on that behaviour to always be the case and should practice good habits (which I forgot) of always explicitly closing them.